# Risk of cross-reference

Tags: c#, cross-reference

I made a class that be called 'A' and that reference 'B' class
In the same time, I made a class that be called 'B' and that reference 'A' class

I made two classes like below

```
class A
{
   private readonly B _b;
   A(B b)
   {
      _b = b;
   }
}

class B
{
   private readonly A _a;
   B(A a)
   {
      _a = a;
   }
}
```

But NInjection did not allow me to make like this pattern.

So, I want to know why cross-reference can't be allowed to do.

Thank you.

Comment: If you can only construct and A with a B and can only construct a B with an A how do you intend to ever construct an A or B to begin with?

Comment: I don't think you should be using a IoC container if you're not super familiar with reference types, interfaces, et. al. What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: this is called circular dependency. not allowed in ninject. can use property injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use property injection to get around cyclic dependency:

```
class A
{
   public B _b {get; set;}
   public void OtherMethod() {}
}

class B
{
   B(A a)
   {
      a._b = this;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the solution proposed by @ Gauravsa is the following: If I have an instance of class B and would like to know which instance of class A has referenced it, there is no way for me to find that out. That is why it is called "cross-referencing", and not "referencing".